# SQL Query For INT Column(identity) to restrict values between 1 to 100

Tags: sql-server, integer, constraints, identity

Suppose we have class with a 100 student limit, we make a column `StudentId` Column between (1-100) beyond this limit `StudentId` is not generated

```
Create Table Class
(
StudentId Int Primary Key Identity(1,1)
StudentName Varchar(25) 
) 


insert into Class values('Jhon')
/* 2 ..
..
..
To 100 (Column) */
insert into Class values('Joy')
```

Record 101

`insert into Class values('Joy')` --- When We insert 101 row a error will occur

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE RegTable
(StudentId NUMBER(8,0),
CONSTRAINT CheckRegNumber  CHECK (StudentId <=100 and StudentId >0 )
);
```

Add a [CONSTRAINT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx) to your `int` column

Comment: I don't think this solution works for identity column. What happens when your `StudentId` is already 100 and you delete rows other than 100. You'll have to `reset` the identity column. Also, if you are not using `identity`, then you'll have to first find the valid Studentid before you can insert the record into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER LimitCount
For INSERT On Student
AS
    If (SELECT COUNT(StudentId) From STUDENT) > 100
       --DO SOMETHING OR ROLLBACK
```

One draw back about this is it doesn't guarantee, if the row are actually 100 if there is deletion. So you will have to do more in DO SOMETHING section

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your `ClassTable` with 100 rows, you could create an `after insert` trigger.  Since your column is `identity` column, you cannot rely on Id, because, you could be in a situation where you can't insert rows but you have less than 100 students. This usually occurs when you insert and delete rows. One way to solve this problem is by `resetting` identity column with `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command, which you do not want to be doing every time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LimitRows
 on ClassTable
 after insert
 as
    declare @rowsCount int
    select @rowsCount = Count(*) from ClassTable
    if @rowsCount > 100
    begin
      rollback
    end
```